# My laptop keep freezing randomly even if I'm not using it

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze

My computer keep freezing randomly.

What I have tried:

- Full fresh format windows 10 with the latest updates.
- Changed my RAM, to 8GB king-stone 1 peace, the same hertz.
- I run memory test "no problems" the same with harddrive but I changed them already.
- Changed my hard-drive to SSD San-disk.
- I cleaned the fan and put a new expensive thermal paste.
- Removed all USB accessories.
- All my drivers from Acer website the latest update.
- My BIOS is the last one too.
- Tried with fresh format without any program on my laptop.

The laptop freeze randomly! sometimes when I'm working on word or text file, sometimes when I came back I found it in freeze,

Note: full freeze like the only way to make it work is to shutdown the Laptop.

I checked the log file and I found these errors after the laptop freezed.

```
Critical    20/04/2019 10:42:57 PM  Kernel-Power    41  (63) <--- I shut down the pc here
Error   20/04/2019 10:43:07 PM  EventLog    6008    None
Error   20/04/2019 08:39:53 PM  Security-SPP    8198    None
Error   20/04/2019 08:31:56 PM  Security-SPP    8198    None
Warning 20/04/2019 08:31:40 PM  User Device Registration    360 None
Error   20/04/2019 08:31:32 PM  TPM 15  None
Error   20/04/2019 06:08:00 AM  DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   20/04/2019 05:41:28 AM  Security-SPP    8198    None
```

I just traced all freezes and before every freeze I found this errors.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP
Date:          16/04/2019 03:56:29 PM
Event ID:      8198
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-N84F4CD
Description:
License Activation (slui.exe) failed with the following error code:
hr=0x8007232B
Command-line arguments:
RuleId=502ff3ba-669a-4674-bbb1-601f34a3b968;Action=AutoActivateSilent;AppId=55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f;SkuId=2de67392-b7a7-462a-b1ca-108dd189f588;NotificationInterval=1440;Trigger=NetworkAvailable
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" Guid="{E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}" EventSourceName="Software Protection Platform Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">8198</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-04-16T12:56:29.568221400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2030</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-N84F4CD</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>hr=0x8007232B</Data>
    <Data>RuleId=502ff3ba-669a-4674-bbb1-601f34a3b968;Action=AutoActivateSilent;AppId=55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f;SkuId=2de67392-b7a7-462a-b1ca-108dd189f588;NotificationInterval=1440;Trigger=NetworkAvailable</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: It's your motherboard. Freezes are normally caused by 3 things. Motherboards, Ram, or your hard drive.

Comment: @Sickest Other things can cause a system to freeze. For example, an over temp CPU will stop processing, causing a system-wide lockup.

Comment: The odds the CPU is overheated are astronomically low.